# Posting JSON Array of Integers

Tags: c#, json, http-post, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I am attempting to POST some JSON data to an API to add accounts.
The instructions specify the ids parameter can be: a string (comma-separated), or **array of integers**

I realize I could put comma delimited ids into the query string however I would like to POST this data as JSON as I may have a large number of these.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    var property = Properties.Settings.Default;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(property.apiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-OrgSync-API-Key", property.apiKey);
    return client;
}

HttpClient client = Api.GetHttpClient();
string json = "{\"ids\":[10545801,10731939]}";
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}/classifications/{classification.id}/accounts/add", httpContent);
```

It runs "successfully" but nothing actually gets set on the API server side.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here?
Additionally, any kind of tools/techniques etc., particularly in Visual Studio that would give me better visibility of the request/response traffic?

I know that this is possible as it correctly adds the account ids when I use a tool like Postman:

[image: Postman Successful Run]

Comment: Well what is the API's action signature?

Comment: This is the only documentation I was provided with:
https://api.orgsync.com/api/docs/v2/classifications/add_accounts

Comment: Are you supplying the other required parameters too?

Comment: I am when I setup the HttpClient.  I added this code to my original question.

Comment: I found if I changed the second parameter to null or Encoding.Default instead of Encoding.UTF8 when setting up the StringContent it works without issue.  I am not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Tools/Techniques, you can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the request and response on the fly to check if the Raw request is correct.

If you haven't used it before, have a look [here](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording) for instructions on how to capture the requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the json string method working by changing the StringContent encoding type from Encoding.UTF8 to null OR Encoding.Default.

```
string json = "{\"ids\":[10545801,10731939]}";
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}/classifications/{classification.id}/accounts/add", httpContent);
```

I also figured out a way to use an object containing an int array of ids with the Encoding.UTF8;

```
HttpClient client = Api.GetHttpClient();
var postData = new PostData {ids = new[] {10545801,10731939}};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}/classifications/{classification.id}/accounts/add", httpContent);
```

If you don't want to go to the trouble of creating a class just to store post data you can use an anonymous type:

```
var postData = new { ids = new[] {10545801,10731939}};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}/classifications/{classification.id}/accounts/add", httpContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work

```
using (var client= new HttpClient()) {
string json = "{\"ids\":[10545801,10731939]}";
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}/classifications/{classification.id}/accounts/add", httpContent);

 // If the response contains content we want to read it!
    if (response .Content != null) {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//you will get your response in responseContent 
}
```